# When use sessions in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies

I need to create a Simple Web Application using `Sessions` and `Cookies` with Servlet. 
I have two pages, Login page and Registration page (a simple form), both are HTML pages.
Have I to use `Session` only for Sign-in or only for Sign-up or both case? And why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transfer data from one page to another page with different requests,you  can 
use `session`.

If you just submit the information from sign-up page and then store the data into database,you need not to use session.

If you need when user sign-up the page go to the sign-in page and show user's name,you can use session like this `session.setAttribute("username",request.getParameter("userName"))` and in other requests you can get it like`session.getAttribute("username")` and send it to page to show who sign-in.